# Count transitions between '0' and '1' in a column with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, count

I have a column with '0' and '1' meaning that a machine is working(0) or not(1). I want to know the number of changes between '1' and '0' in order to know the working periods. 
Example:

0000000111110000000011111100000011111111111111111000000000( in column)

The cicle will be having 0 change to 1 and change back to 0. 
In the example there will be 3 cicles.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say a column, but you don't show a column, you show what looks like a string. So I've assumed it's a string.

```
Dim s As String
s = "0000000111110000000011111100000011111111111111111000000000"
Do While InStr(s, "00")
    s = Replace(s, "00", "0")
Loop
Do While InStr(s, "11")
    s = Replace(s, "11", "1")
Loop
MsgBox (Len(s) - 1) / 2 & " cycles." '3 cycles.
```

But if you do have them in a column, then this array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>) works for me:

```
=SUM(IF(A2:A58-A1:A57<>0,1))/2
```

assuming your 58 zeroes and ones are in range A1:A58.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It's a column of lenght 38681. So I have 38681 '1' and '0'. I am not sure I understand your solution for columns, but for arrays it looks like pretty well. I would be grateful if you update the answer. Thank you again.